# Selenium-How to iterate through webPage to Find all Necessary elements and perform Click Action

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a Method for finding the element via Xpath and perform Click action but if element is available on Next page how can i do that ? I know i can find the xpath for next page and click it and look through it . But i want to come back to initial page as well.

For example I have 20 Elements found by xpath:

```
IList<IWebElement> Test= SeleniumDriver.WebDriver.FindElements(By.Xpath(""));
```

and if above will find 20 elements then i m running foreach loop. SO it can able to do all action as i needed but if first page got only 10 element then how can i go to next page for to find the remaining ones . Also in "Test"  i'm not getting all the elements in order. So my foreach loop will find first 2 and might be 3rd one it tries to find will go to next page so i have to go to next page and find the element , validate it and then come back to initial page .

Please let me know if any easy way ?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can write logic something like this

```
IList<IWebElement> Test= SeleniumDriver.WebDriver.FindElements(By.Xpath(""));
for each WebElement ele {
if(isElementPresent(ele) {
   do Operation with ele
}
 else {
   go to second page
}
if(isElementPresent(ele) 
   do Operation with ele
Go to 1st page

}
```

Comment: I'm having 2 foreach loop inside the first Foreach loop. So i think above will be really complecated.

Also we are using if(isElementPresent(ele) 2 times and if thats the case then i will have foeach loop again 2 more time so it will look really complected. Is there we can loop through both if ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have table with information you will have button to next page (if it exist)
so what you need to do is taking the elements like you did in while loop and check if next button exist if yes click on it and repeat taking the elements until button is exist

the best way is doing it by (pseudocode):

```
do
{
IList<IWebElement> Test= SeleniumDriver.WebDriver.FindElements(By.Xpath(""));

//HERE YOU CHECK IF BUTTON EXIST
if(isElementPresented(By.Id("")))
{
driver.FindElement(By.Id("")).Click;
}
else
{
//if button not exists
buttonExist = false;
}
}while(buttonExist);
```